# Referencing own DNX class library from web project

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, dnx, asp.net-core

I am trying to structure my new application with the help of Dependency Injection.

Created a Autofac module that i want to register with the IServiceCollection interface.

```
 public class PlanrModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            //builder.Register(c => new Logger())
            //    .As<ILogger>()
            //    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
    }
```

**The problem is that** i can't reference the Successful.Core.Ioc project, don't ask me why, everything seems correct.

```
using Successful.Core.Ioc.Modules;

namespace Successful.Planr.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Create the Autofac container builder.
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Add any Autofac modules or registrations.
            builder.RegisterModule(new PlanrModule());

            // Populate the services.
            builder.Populate(services);

            // Build the container.
            var container = builder.Build();

            // Resolve and return the service provider.
            return container.Resolve<IServiceProvider>();
        }
```

Is there something wrong with the code? Or is the problem relative to my vs setup/installation?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i found the answer my self. The project that i referenced was a dnx451 project and my web project was a aspnet project.

Changed so both projects use the dnx runtime.